# xml parsing from web service image's

Tags: iphone

I need to parse xml. my xml do have image links.....

Example my xml..

```
<root>
<child id='1'> child One</child>
<childe2> Child two </child2>
<image>http://website........link.</image>
<image>http://website........link.</image>
<image>http://website........link.</image>
</root>
```

now i have taken NSMutableArray for loading images....

is this procedure is correct.  any alternative i can implement.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this approach is correct and shouldn't cause problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong in this approach.
Make the `NSMutableArray` as an ivar,
Parse the XML,Create an `NSMutableArray` when you find the "image" tag in the `didStartElement` (`NSXMLParser` Delegate), push items into the array in the `didEndElement` and get the images from the array when you need it.